# IntelliJでGo Lang Pluginがで出てこない

Tags: go, intellij-idea

IntelliJでConfigure>PluginのBrowseRepogitoryから
「Go Lang Plugin」を選択/インストールしたいのですが、
Goと打ち込んでもなにも出現しません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

調べた結果出てきた、Configure>Plugins>ManageRepogitoyへ
alphaのリポジトリURLを入力するということも行ってみたのですが、
上の画像にあるようなGoのつくものは出てきたものの、GoLangは含まれていませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑を見る限り、そもそもURLにプラグインがないと言われているようです。

HTTPプロキシは設定済ですが、立ち上げてプラグインに繋ぐと、
以下のようなエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どなたか解決策に思い当たることがあればご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

”The selected directory is not a valid home for Go SDK”
というエラーワードが出てきました。

結果、appengine内のgorootフォルダのVERSIONファイルの中身が、
go1.8.3ではなく、1.8.3のみのテキストになっていたからのようでした。